# Please I need help with that CMakeList

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to use a cnny_vision at my fuerte.But I can't build a executable named ar_single.

I can't find any problem with my CMakeList, but someone could find any error with that?

```
    cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.4.6) include($ENV{ROS_ROOT}/core/rosbuild/rosbuild.cmake)
    # Set the build type.  Options are:
    #  Coverage       : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization, w/ code-coverage
    #  Debug          : w/ debug symbols, w/o optimization
    #  Release        : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization
    #  RelWithDebInfo : w/ debug symbols, w/ optimization
    #  MinSizeRel     : w/o debug symbols, w/ optimization, stripped binaries
    #set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE RelWithDebInfo) set(ROS_BUILD_TYPE Debug) rosbuild_init()
    #set the default path for built executables to the "bin" directory set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)
    #set the default path for built libraries to the "lib" directory set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
    #uncomment if you have defined messages rosbuild_genmsg()
    #uncomment if you have defined services
    #rosbuild_gensrv()
    #common commands for building c++ executables and libraries
    #rosbuild_add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/example.cpp)
    #target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} another_library)
    #rosbuild_add_boost_directories()
    #rosbuild_link_boost(${PROJECT_NAME} thread)
    #rosbuild_add_executable(example examples/example.cpp)
    #target_link_libraries(example ${PROJECT_NAME})
 include_directories('/usr/local/include/') 
 link_directories('/usr/local/lib/')

 set(ARPOSESINGLE       ar_single) 
 set(ARPOSESINGLE_SRC   src/ar_single.cpp) 
set(ARPOSESINGLE_LIBS  GLU GL glut ARgsub AR ARMulti ARvideo) 
set(ARPOSEMULTI       ar_multi) 
set(ARPOSEMULTI_SRC   src/ar_multi.cpp src/object.cpp) set(ARPOSEMULTI_LIBS  GLU GL glut ARgsub AR ARMulti ARvideo)
 rosbuild_add_executable(${ARPOSESINGLE} ${ARPOSESINGLE_SRC})
 target_link_libraries(${ARPOSESINGLE}  ${ARPOSESINGLE_LIBS})
 rosbuild_add_executable(${ARPOSEMULTI} ${ARPOSEMULTI_SRC}) 
 target_link_libraries(${ARPOSEMULTI}  ${ARPOSEMULTI_LIBS})
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/131881/please-i-need-help-with-that-cmakelist/) by [JoaoPedro](https://answers.ros.org/users/12316/joaopedro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-02-21

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I think the problem in these lines that has been commented:

```
rosbuild_init()

set(EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/bin)

set(LIBRARY_OUTPUT_PATH ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib)
```

---

Originally posted by [Hamid Didari](https://answers.ros.org/users/6486/hamid-didari/) with karma: 1769 on 2014-02-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't see anything obviously wrong with your CMakeLists.txt.

If you can add the commands you're running and the error you're seeing to your question, that would be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-21

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1